# Xamarin base ContentPage with loading (or common ContentViews)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, content-pages

how can I create a "base" `ContentPage` that contains, for sample, a `busy indicator`, and make this `Page` the base for each other pages inside my application?

I have tried to do in this way, but the `busy indicator` isn't showed.

**Base Page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:SgatMobileV3.Core;assembly=SgatMobileV3"
             x:Class="SgatMobileV3.Core.BasePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <core:VolosLoadingView />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Busy indicator view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:SgatMobileV3.Core;assembly=SgatMobileV3"
             core:LocatorViewModel.AutoWireViewModel="true"
             x:Class="SgatMobileV3.Core.VolosLoadingView"
             xmlns:busyindicator="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms">

    <Grid>
     <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.6" IsVisible="True" />
     <busyindicator:SfBusyIndicator
        IsBusy="True"
        IsVisible="True"
        x:Name="loading" AnimationType="DoubleCircle"
        ViewBoxWidth="150" ViewBoxHeight="150"
        TextColor="Green" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>       
     </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

**A page:**

```
<core:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:SgatMobileV3.Core;assembly=SgatMobileV3"
             core:LocatorViewModel.AutoWireViewModel="true"
             x:Class="SgatMobileV3.Views.MockPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Button Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms! 1"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Command="{Binding Test_ClickCommand}" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</core:BasePage>
```

I have tried to include a sample `label` inside the **base page** but nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I create a "base" ContentPage that contains, for sample, a busy indicator, and make this Page the base for each other pages

If want Creating a `ControlTemplate` at Page Level,creating `ControlTemplate` instances at the application level, they can also be created at the page level, as shown in the [following code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating#creating-a-controltemplate-in-c):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SimpleTheme.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="TealTemplate">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="AquaTemplate">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentView ... ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TealTemplate}">
        ...
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

When adding a `ControlTemplate` at the page level, a `ResourceDictionary` is added to the ContentPage`, and then the`ControlTemplate` instances are included in the ResourceDictionary.

And also can use [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating#creating-a-controltemplate-in-c) , from doc has [a sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/templates/controltemplates/simpletheme/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that adding the control in the code (in BasePage.cs file), I don't think there is XAML solution for that.